# Alterning LED's in breadboard with timer 555, 2 circuits doing the same but i don't understand one of them

Tags: led, capacitor, integrated-circuit, 555, breadboard

I am working on an alternating LED circuit. Initially, I implemented it following the circuit shown below.

[image]

From this circuit, I understand that the capacitor discharges from R2 to the discharge pin (7) and charges from both R1 and R2. It charges from both of them because R1 is connected to the power source, and R2 is connecting R1 to the capacitor. Essentially, here we are charging through 2 resistors but only discharging through 1.

However, I came across a similar circuit on YouTube that puzzled me.

New circuit:

[image]

In this circuit, I don't understand how the capacitor charges or discharges. Shouldn't it be connected to the discharge pin to discharge? And shouldn't it be connected to the power to charge? Additionally, I'm unsure why R1 is connected to the output (3).

Comment: Would you please use the built in editor to replace the images with proper circuit diagrams?

Comment: R1 is connected to the output so that when the output is high, the capacitor charges, and when the output is low, the capacitor discharges. It's one way to get closer to a 50% duty cycle.